# Active class on scroll with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to active class in scroll when i'm going to second page h1 must translate and become visible but i think there is something wrong with my js code

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let fadeText = document.querySelector('.fade');
  if (window.scrollY < window.innerHeight) {
    fadeText.classList.add('fade-in');
  }
});
```

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.fade {
  font-size: 5em;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  /* Add a default opacity value */
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out, opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.fade_in {
  opacity: 1;
  /* Change opacity to 1 when the 'fade-in' class is added */
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="section">1</div>

<div class="section">3
  <h1 class="fade">ELEMENTS</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add more details please?

Comment: Details about what?

Comment: For example, have you check when your class can be added? Does your page reach the condition?

Comment: in hear i did't give ani condition becouse if i give any numbers to scrollY there will different resolutions it will not work corectly

Comment: i want when i'm going to second page text become visible that all     like in this link    https://interior-define.com/

Comment: You can take a look to intersectionObserver maybe it can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show the text 'Element' when you scroll to the next section which contains 3 then you should remove 'fade' class too as currently you are having 2 class on 1 element and because of that there is only 1 css is applying, in your case, its opacity 0 so you just have to upgrade the js with class remove and you are ready to go.

Instead of this code

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let fadeText = document.querySelector('.fade');
  if (window.scrollY < window.innerHeight) {
    fadeText.classList.add('fade-in');
  }
});
```

use this one

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let fadeText = document.querySelector('.fade');
  if (window.scrollY < window.innerHeight) {
  
    fadeText.classList.add('fade-in');
    fadeText.classList.remove('fade');
  }
});
```

and your issue will be solved.  Let me know if there is any other issue.

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2oexgfd0/1/)

As you have mentioned in comment that you want to make section like given example then [read here](https://css-tricks.com/books/greatest-css-tricks/scroll-animation/) for scorll animation or you can check [this beautiful animation](https://codepen.io/abdulrazakshaikh/pen/aaeBBm) demo which is the same you want.

Comment: one thing else in my web page in css i have this parametre  overflow-y: scroll;  when i'm adding it js function is not working

Comment: please share the code as i don't think js code will stop by changing css.

Comment: .container {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}
.section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}